# Can a summoner lose even more LP than zero?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I'm not mistaken, you lose more lp after zero, only when you afk.

I remember seeing someone have -3LP before.

Can you lose even more LP than that? How much before reaching the limit (aka getting demoted)?

Comment: Getting demoted is based on mmr, not lp

Comment: Yeah but the system somehow instead of demoting you, they leave you with negative league points, doesn't make sense for me at all but it's the way it works right now, and now I'm wondering how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dodging queue will result in -3LP but no change in real MMR. So you can dodge 10 games and be -30LP but your MMR will still stay same. You can see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209734/how-is-lp-calculated/209741#209741) for LP Calculation

Comment: However if you dodge some ranked games consecutively, the LP loss will increase.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at 0lp and you dodge a queue you get -3lp so hence seeing -3, but you will not be demoted from the dodge.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience I got dc'd after a game and after that I found myself with -3 lp. After that I lost another game and got demoted right away.